# Outlook VBA to Replace Tokens from an email template

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm creating a few macros that open specific Outlook templates an allow you to replace specific tokens before sending the email. It seems to work, but I'm admittedly doing full loops when I probably don't *need to*. So I'm just wondering if anyone sees a better way to approach this.

As you can see below, `loop through entire dictionary` is a common enough theme

Basic synopsis:

1. Define a regex, in my case anything in square brackets get replaced
2. Loop through the Subject and the Body looking for tokens
3. Add each token to a dictionary so that I have unique tokens and only need to provide a replacement string once
4. Loop through the entire dictionary and get replacement strings
5. Loop through the entire dictionary and replace each token in the Subject
6. Loop through the entire dictionary and replace each token in the Body

````vb
Sub FindAndReplaceTokens(TemplatePath As String)
Dim regexObject As Object 'RegEx to find and capture the tokens
Dim Matches As Object 'Collection of matches
Dim dict As Object 'Dictionary to keep unique tokens and their replacement values
Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem 'The email itself
Dim oString As String 'Original strings to be replaced
Dim newString As String 'Replacement strings
Dim i As Integer 'counter for looping through Matches
Dim key As Variant 'counter for looping through dictionary
Dim SubjectReplace As Boolean 'True if the subject has a token to replace
Dim BodyReplace As Boolean 'True if body has a token to replace

'Create the email earlier in case there are issues with this, at least we'll know first thing
'TemplatePath should be the full path ending in .oft identifying the template we're using
Set NewMail = CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplatePath)

Set regexObject = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regexObject
        .Pattern = "(\[[^\]]+\])"
        .Global = True
End With
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Check for replacements in the subject
If regexObject.test(NewMail.Subject) Then
    SubjectReplace = True
    Set Matches = regexObject.Execute(NewMail.Subject)
    For i = 0 To (Matches.Count - 1)
        'Debug.Print Matches(i).SubMatches(0)
        oString = Matches(i).SubMatches(0)
        dict(oString) = dict(oString) + 1
    Next i
End If

'Check for replacements in the body
If regexObject.test(NewMail.Body) Then
    BodyReplace = True
    Set Matches = regexObject.Execute(NewMail.Body)
    For i = 0 To (Matches.Count - 1)
        'Debug.Print Matches(i).SubMatches(0)
        oString = Matches(i).SubMatches(0)
        dict(oString) = dict(oString) + 1
    Next i
End If

If SubjectReplace Or BodyReplace Then
    For Each key In dict.keys
        'Debug.Print key, dict(key)
        newString = InputBox("What should be used in place of " & key & "?", "Replacement for " & dict(key) & " of " & key)
        If newString = "" Then newString = key
        dict(key) = newString
        'Debug.Print key, dict(key)
    Next key
    With NewMail
        If SubjectReplace Then
            For Each key In dict.keys
                .Subject = Replace(.Subject, key, dict(key))
            Next key
        End If
        If BodyReplace Then
            If .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain Then
                For Each key In dict.keys
                    .Body = Replace(.Body, key, dict(key))
                Next key
            ElseIf .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
                For Each key In dict.keys
                    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, key, dict(key))
                Next key
            End If
        End If
    End With
End If

'Display the message
NewMail.Display

End Sub
```
````

Comment: The fact that you have to have a comment to describe each variable you're declaring tells me that your variable names aren't very good. For example, `SubjectReplace` could be named `replacementInSubject`, then your statement later reads `If replacementInSubject or replaementInBody Then`. Makes it read a bit more English-like and eliminates the need for the comment. Lather, rinse, repeat on other variable names.